# How to change the bookmarked line's check mark color in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

In PHPStorm version 4 a line can be bookmarked by pressing F11 while the caret is on that line. This produces a black check mark, next to that line, in the gutter.

I have looked in the JetBrains documentation, Google, and searched thoroughly inside the IDE's settings (File > Settings > IDE settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts), but have been unable to locate a setting that would allow for the check mar color to be changed.

Any ideas how this might be changed?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot change color for check-mark icon unfortunately.** Because it is bitmap (image) and not text symbol or something that is freely drawn at runtime -- just like breakpoint image is.

Related ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-72041  (and maybe http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-39879 )

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the references, too, LazyOne! You roxxor :)